# Is the edit window broken for everyone or just me?

Tags: support, editor, browser-cache

The edit toolbar is not showing for me, neither is the preview.
It is working here on Meta though.

Is there something broken with the WMD or is it just me?

Comment: Clear your cache.

Comment: That worked. What could have possibly happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, it is just you and everybody else whose browser caches files regardless of the little query string appended to the requests.

Your cached version of the site's JavaScript file was out of date. Hence, a clearing reload and flush of your browser cache fixes the problem by calling for a fresh file.