# Super User Edit ( Format Icons are missing )

Tags: discussion, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the edit window broken for everyone or just me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27385/is-the-edit-window-broken-for-everyone-or-just-me)

http://yfrog.com/6wbugygp

while editing this question :[Firefox: Streaming video download](https://superuser.com/questions/72611/firefox-streaming-video-download)

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27385/is-the-edit-window-broken-for-everyone-or-just-me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens if something is screwed up in your cache, or if you can't reach Google for some reason.

It happened to me this morning - clear your browser cache, and try again.