# Just me or everyone? Edit Question is totally broken, see screenshot

Tags: support, edits, editor

As you can see in the screenshot, the edit question seems totally broken on StackOverflow (not on Meta). This also happens when I click *Ask Question*.

Notice the empty preview, the missing buttons, the non-working shortcuts (i.e., Ctrl-L for a link and Ctrl-I for italics don't work anymore). I'm using FF 3.6.6

*This is not a double of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27385/is-the-edit-window-broken-for-everyone-or-just-me), because of its age and the current situation is just new.*

[image: Dumpt.com]

Comment: Apparently it happened only for a short while. It seems to have gone now. Maybe I was just editing between two server updates?

Comment: Just you. Works fine for me.

Comment: @Abel There haven't been any updates to SO today

Comment: @Amir, thanks for testing. @Michael, thanks for checking. \\\ Mmm, odd. Just like in the referring question, where it was mentioned that it's cache issues causing this. Maybe my cache was partially invalidated, which caused (parts of) the javascript to not be loaded, and other parts to work? Like I said, odd...

Comment: @Abel, you can always tell when the last update was [by looking at the footer](http://img.skitch.com/20100801-fn9g1746eha24cusy852s7dp2a.png).

Comment: @Arjan: great tip! So there was an update, but a day before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appears, the browser caches the javascript, regardless whether the javascript url has a random-token appended (or the random token was not so random after all — 42) to prevent caching. According to [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27385/is-the-edit-window-broken-for-everyone-or-just-me), this can happen regularly and result in outdated javascript to be loaded.

Not sure whether this could be solved by code (i.e., it should be trivial to check for the objects to be there and to issue a warning to the user to flush his cache, it will be less trivial to solve the caching issue), but when it happens, it sure looks rather scary.

Comment: it is our consensus that you are behind a broken proxy when this happens. If the URL changes, and the proxy continues to cache it..

Comment: Unless you meanwhile cleared the cache, you might see multiple versions in `about:cache?device=disk`.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I can be positive that I'm not behind any proxy (unless browsers nowadays proxy themselves), not even from my ISP. \\\ @Arjan: I can't find multiple versions, but I did a Ctrl-R which may have taken care of that already.

Comment: A Ctrl-R shouldn't clear the existing cache. It will ask the server if known caches for specific URLs are still valid (most likely by using `If-Modified-Since`). But it won't clear caches of URLs that are not even used in the page for which you hit Ctrl-R. Request both `http://sstatic.net/js/question.js?v=v1` and `http://sstatic.net/js/question.js?v=v2`, reload `about:cache?device=disk` to validate both are cached, then hit Ctrl-R for the last URL, and reload the cache results again. The `?v=v1` is still there (and you'll see updates in the details for `?v=v2`).

Comment: @Arjan: I understand that it will not clear all cache, that's why I use it in the first place. But it forces a refresh with conditional HTTP requests of all resources (or, I though, it just requests them again unconditionally, you can notice this with the slow loading of images after Ctrl-R). Most importantly: in this scenario, it works. If you needed to clear your *whole* cache for just viewing a site correctly, then there's something seriously wrong.

Comment: My point is: Ctrl-R should not clear the cache of anything that's not on the page. If the current page does not include `?x=y` then the cache for `?x=y` should not be cleared (assuming it has not otherwise expired). Odd that your cache does not show the old `question.js` versions.