# Editor toolbar not showing up

Tags: support, bug, toolbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WYSIWYG editor missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132133/wysiwyg-editor-missing)

Recently, the editor toolbar on Stack Overflow hasn't been showing up for me (it is on THIS site, though!). What's going on? It's really annoying not to be able to format code. Seems to be happening both with Chrome and IE.

Also, the handle at the bottom of the text area which is used for re-sizing is missing.

Comment: This post suggests clearing your cache: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27385.  In the meantime, you can format code with ctrl-k or manually tabbing in with four spaces.

Comment: Clearing the cache didn't seem to make a difference. In the meantime, I'll try using ctrl-K for formatting code. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related: [I cannot see the formatting toolbar on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131654)

Comment: @birdus - are you at work behind a proxy? if so can you see if they're using McAfee SmartFilter?

Comment: I am behind a proxy. However, the toolbar is now appearing. I have no idea what changed.