# I do not see the upload image options on stackoverflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Editor toolbar not showing up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131836/editor-toolbar-not-showing-up)

When I ask/edit a question on www.stackoverflow.com I am unable to upload photos etc... as these options are no longer visible, I can see attached options on http://meta.stackoverflow.com when asking a question but not on stackoverflow ?

[image]

Comment: Your *entire toolbar* is missing? Or just the ability to upload images?

Comment: @The Establishment The entire toolbar is missing, just checking the dulpicates now

Comment: @The Establishment Is there a keyboard shortcut for uploading images?

Comment: Yes, `Ctrl`+`G`.

Comment: @The Establishment Ctrl+G opens find dialog on Chrome

Comment: It should not, not if you have focus set on the edit textbox. But it might if JavaScript is broken for you, which would be the reason why you're not seeing the toolbar in the first place.

Comment: @The Establishment Using firebug I receive the error : "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/" Is this related ?

Comment: If you browse in office, [this comment by Nick](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131654/i-cannot-see-the-formatting-toolbar-on-stack-overflow#comment363296_131654) might answer your case as well. (your company is blocking the host of required JS file)