# Strange behavior while trying to edit a question

Tags: discussion, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Editor toolbar not showing up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131836/editor-toolbar-not-showing-up)

Today I was trying to edit a question, and I was not able to see the tools tab.

[image: Screenshot 1]

I had to simply press the escape to get back from the edit mode, but when I pressed the escape key, I ran into this.

[image: screenshot 2]

Why did this occur? What was going wrong? I am using Google Chrome running on Linux.

Comment: @Nick why the influx of those bug reports? Some CDN pushed into a black list?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - some virus company mis-flagged our wmd.js as a virus, which causes all sorts of downstream chaos for those that consume/apply those malware lists.  False positives are a tremendous pain in the ass for us, this isn't the first time it's happened.

Comment: @Nick yep I remember something like that - isn't there a way to tell those companies to always trust stuff from a certain domain?